# Single WCF service with two basicHttpBindings https endpoints

Tags: wcf

Please help!,

First of all, does on the same site we can defined two https bindings?

I use basicHttpBinding,

In single WCF service I add two https endpoints, one with security:

```
<security mode="Transport">
     <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"                  
                       proxyCredentialType="None"/>         
</security> 

<endpoint address="https://xxx.svc" /> default port 443
```

other:

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" 
            proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>           
</security>

<endpoint address="https://yyy:4430/xxx.svc" />
```

In serviceHostingEnvironment I add prefix in baseAddressPrefixFilters

```
<add prefix="https://xxx.svc"/>
```

and when try browsing service got following error:
The SSL settings for the service 'SslRequireCert' does not match those of the IIS 'Ssl, SslMapCert'.

I tried all combination on IIS (7.0) for SSL settings, and i had add bindings for port 443 and 4430

Comment: I'm desperate, please help!!!!!!

Comment: Try this: set the directory security->Secure communication->require SSL. Anyway, this link also may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751408.aspx

Comment: I create two web application(wcf service) one require SSL and client certificate, and on another require SSL but ignore client certificate (use windows authentication) but still don't work , help

Comment: Is anyone can help me, plese!!!!????